# Cannot install ember-cli on mac OS X

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm

When I try to install ember-cli via npm, following the official documentation, I get this error:

```
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23) 

gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sandropalmieri/npm-debug.log
```

I 've tried several times running the command using sudo but still getting this kind of error. Any idea of what's going on? Can you please assist? Thanks

Comment: Note that if you used `sudo` you may have broken permissions for subsequent runs, which will cause you headaches.

Comment: without sudo I could not do the installation. I tried first without sudo but I was deny permission..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding --no-optional to your npm install command.

Are you using npm 3.3.3? See issue here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4873

Comment: Yes you were right. There is an issue with npm and ember-cli. I 've added --no optional and now it works even tough I got a the following message "Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v4.0.0. Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js."  What does it mean exactly ? They want me to use an older version of node?

Comment: I think the Ember-CLI team just needs to update their hard-coded values for which Node versions are "okay". Node jumping from 0.12 to 4.0.0 may have screwed up their arithmetic if they had any. The newest NPM / Node packages have broken a number of things for different packages for me, so I'm treating any and all weirdness as a part of that. For the time being I've downgraded npm to the previous version and things are going much better.

Answer (score 0):

install node

node -v

v12.14.1

which npm

/usr/local/bin/npm

npm -v

6.13.4

npm install --save core-js@^3

sudo npm install -g ember-cli

which ember

/usr/local/bin/ember

ember -v

ember-cli: 3.16.0

node: 12.16.1

os: darwin x64